# How do I make an image an anchor in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have read other threads on how to do this and they do not work for me. Can someone tell me how to make an image a anchor in CI?

I have tried these:

```
<li><?php echo anchor("Home",img("../application/images/Home_up.png")); ?></li>
```

and

```
<li><?php echo anchor("Home",img("src"=>"../application/images/Home_up.png")); ?></li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the url helper loaded either via the contoller `($this->load->helper('url');`) or via the helper array in `/system/application/config/autoload.php`; try:

```
anchor('Home',img(array('src'=>'../application/images/Home_up.png','border'=>'0','alt'=>'Home')));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried assigning the img function to a variable, and passing that to the anchor function? Something along the lines of:

```
<?php $img = img('../application/images/Home_up.png'); ?>
<li><?php echo anchor('home', $img); ?></li>
```

Be sure you have the HTML and URL helpers loaded.

Edit @Dolph and everyone else: This is now **TESTED**. It **WORKS** as of 1.7.2.

Perhaps instead of downvoting me, you could have tested it yourself and proved me wrong. Also, I don't see anywhere in his original post anything like the above code. He passed the img function output right into the anchor function - which does not always work. Two functions that spring to mind that wont let you do this are isset and empty. There are many more.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to make an image anchor.
There are some functions that override the anchor() function though, search in the CI forums and wiki.

Comment: You're right. Didn't know the img() function. Your answer is correct then :)